# standard user start process , and process have administrator privilege without input administrator password

Tags: privilege-elevation

The privilege elevation lets standard user of non-administrative users to an administrator level necessary for some executables. As a result, the users can start some executables as if they are members of the administrators group.
how to achieve this feature on the Windows platform？